# Exact match for 404 errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The code below allows `example.com/bed/` and `example.com/table/` and returns 404 errors for all other URLs with this structure: `example.com/$$$/`

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*\/    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bed|table [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

The problem is 404 errors doesn't work for these structures:
`example.com/$$$bed$$$/` and `example.com/$$$table$$$/`

So how can I change the code to allow only exact match but NOT partial match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I change the code to allow only exact match but NOT partial match.

Use anchors in your regex pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(bed|table)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule / - [L,R=404]
```

Regex pattern `!^/(bed|table)/?$` will match everything except `/bed/` and `/table/` (with trailing slash optional).

Also note that you take out one extra `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*\/` because that can be taken care of in `RewriteRule` itself.